# Highcharts data off by one day

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

I have a Highchart that I cannot seem to fix. The dates on the xAxis are correct but the dates on the labels are off by one day. No matter what data I pass to my chart it is always off by one day. I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. Any tips would be appreciated.

You can see my code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/brenjt/zxBTG/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I added time info to the axis and tooltip see http://jsfiddle.net/gATfu/
It looks like your timestamps are from 10pm but the axis labels are showing 0am ... thats why the points look about one day shifted.

Answer (score 23):

Just found your question... I think the solution to your problem is to set up the UTC timezone option to false. This will set up the chart timezone to be local and not UTC.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global : {
        useUTC : false
    }
});
```

See: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC

Comment: This solved the issue apparently, but I don't understand why this cannot be set right from the initial chart config, instead of invoking setOptions. Anyone to explain ?

Comment: @MrWater, I'm not sure why you need to invoke `setOptions` other than that the documentation seems to allow it only through there. The documentation for how this setting impacts matters is very clear here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC

Answer (score 2):

it's because of the timezone. You should convert you date in UTC format with Date.UTC(..). It will work

Comment: I have converted my date using Date.UTC() but no luck, had to use the solution provided by @Tony

Answer (score 1):

The global HighCharts option for UTC worked quite good. I cannot yet vote that one up :(

I also figured out that HighCharts moves my bar chart according to the exact time stamp as described by dgw. I.e. a date from the 1st of May can be shown in the near of 30th of April depending on the scaling. That confused me because there were two 30th of April entries and no 1st of May.